# How to merge rows in a table that has been read from a word doc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-docx

I'm currently working on a small project whereby I'm collecting all of my brokerage platform's monthly statements, reading in a specific table for each month's statement, and then later on graphing my monthly portfolio value.

I'm struggling with fixing the apparently crappy formating that the table is being processed in. I would need a df that has data for each stock in just one row with data in each column.

My dataframe currently looks as follows:

| # of Stocks | Name | Price | Total Value Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Apple Inc US0378331005 | 200 | 1000 |
| 5 | Microsoft |  | 500 |
|  | Corporation |  |  |
|  | US5949181045 | 100 |  |
| 10 | Something US123434534545 | 10 | 100 |

So I was wondering how to maybe write a for-loop that can do the following:

1. If the value in any row of the first column is empty ( np.nan(df.loc[,0]) == True )
2. Then copy the value in each column of that row and merge/concatenate it with each respective column in the row above
3. Delete the row that has an empty first column
4. Next

Something along the lines of:

```
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if np.nan(df.iloc[[0]])==True:
            #Take each value in this row and append to the respective column above
            df.drop(df.index[row])
        else:
            next()
```

I'm not even sure how to start on that line of code though.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby`:

```
# Print `blocks` to see why it represents the blocks we are interested in
blocks = df['# of Stocks'].notna().cumsum()

df.groupby(blocks).agg({
    '# of Stocks': 'first',
    'Name' : ' '.join,
    'Price': 'first',
    'Total Value Position': 'first'
})
```

Comment: For some reason the .join command doesn't manage to pull the lower rows values up. I'm not sure if that has to do with the blocks command not working properly.

Comment: @germany check the updated answer. I might have screwed up, should be `notna()`, not `isna()`.

Comment: Can you try again, `blocks` should be `1,2,2,2,3` for the sample data.

Comment: Thank you Quang! You were very helpful :)

Comment: Last question @Quang, how do I drop the empty rows? I tried doing it with df = df[df['# of Stocks'].notna()] but that didn't work. When I print the df, I also don't see NaN values, which would explain why it doesnt work...

Comment: @germany the code did not return what you want? or do you want to reassign `df = df.groupby(...)`?

Comment: Oh, they may be the empty strings, not `nan`. So try `blocks = df['# of Stocks'].ne('').cumsum()`.